# is it possible that at the end of the prompt has a "$" when using root user?

Tags: root, prompt

I saw a prompt having the structure root@machine : /root $, does it mean that it is being used the root user?

Comment: Prompts are controlled by the PS1 environment variable. One can make the prompt say ANYTHING! Read `man bash $SHELL`.

Answer (score 1):

Prompts can lie but usually they don't, obviously. But `root@` and `/root` (as no other user should be able to enter that directory) both pretty much mean that it is a root shell.

Answer (score 0):

Prompt can be different according to the settings of your shell. Normally it's controlled by environment variable "PS1", you can print your prompt string by the following commands :

> echo $PS1

or

> printenv | grep PS1

And change this prompt string permanently by editing your bash config file. For example, the ~/.bashrc.